# Irreducibility of q-factorial plus 1

Tags: polynomials, q-analogs

Let $q$ be a formal variable and for every positive integer $n$ let
$$[n]_q! = 1 (1 + q)(1 + q + q^2) \dotsm (1 + q + \dotsb + q^{n-1})$$
be the [$q$-factorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-Factorial.html).

Is it true that $[n]_q! + 1$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$ for all positive integers $n$?

I already [asked this question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3123746/irreducibility-of-q-factorial-plus-1), and [Sil](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/290240/sil) [verified it up to $n = 117$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3123746/irreducibility-of-q-factorial-plus-1#comment6437586_3123746).